# Pyramid of asterisk

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to write code using a for loop to print a pyramid of asterisks. The height of the pyramid should be determined by the user input and should look like:

ex: input of 3

> *
>   **
>   ***
>   **
>   *

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework6_Project2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int triangleHeight = keyboard.nextInt();
        int i;
        int j;
        for (i = triangleHeight; i >= 1; i--) {
            for (j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

edit: I was forgetting the code for the bottom half where I needed to use the ++ increment operator.

Comment: It's printing exactly what you're asking it to print - you begin counting with three, print three asterisks and moving to the new line. Then you print two. You need to first print while taking the loop up in ascending order. Then when you reach the number, you continue moving down.

Answer (score 1):

You need another looping to print the upper pyramids.

Something like:

```
for(i = 1; i < triangleHeight; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

You can check [this](https://ideone.com/tpyy5d) code which gave me the following output for input `3`:

> *
>   **
>   ***
>   **
>   *

Answer (score 0):

public class PyramidOfAsterisk {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    java.util.Scanner keyboard = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    int pyramidHeight = keyboard.nextInt();

    for(int i = 1; i <= pyramidHeight; i++){
        for(int j=1; j <= i; j++){
            System.out.print('*');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    for(int i = pyramidHeight - 1; i > 0; i--){
        for(int j=i; j > 0; j--){
            System.out.print('*');
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```